# How to retrun a String in Kotlin Initialization

Tags: kotlin

I have the following Firebase Initialization, how can I make it return snapshot so that when I call it I get the val snapshot?

```
var homeRef_Host_Name: Unit = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid)
    .child("name")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
           val snapshot = snapshot.value.toString()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun getValue(callback:(String)->Unit){
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid)
    .child("name")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            callback(snapshot.value.toString())
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
```

}

```
fun main(){
    getValue { 
        var yourvariable = it
        //place your further code here
    }
}
```

you cant directly assign it to variable because it async operation